# Mapping an interface to concrete class

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this weird behavior of AutoMapper. If I have a class that implements two interfaces were both of them are registered in `CreateMap` only one of them gets mapped and I do not understand why. It looks as if AutoMapper mapped only interface that is mentioned at first place in interfaces list.

Any thoughts? Please, checkout the following [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/epYr06) to see what the problem is.

**Code from fiddler**

A DTO to which I'd like to map:

```
class Dto {
    public string StringValue {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

Interfaces - sources from which I'd like to map:

```
interface ISourceA {
    int Value {get;}
}

interface ISourceB {
    string StringValue {get;}
}
```

...and two implementations for those. One that works, the other not really :/

```
class MultiSource: ISourceA, ISourceB {
    private readonly string _s;
    private readonly int _v;

    public MultiSource(int v, string s) {
        _v = v;
        _s = s;
    }

    int ISourceA.Value { get { return _v; }}
    string ISourceB.StringValue { get { return _s; }}
}

class StringSource: ISourceB {
    public StringSource(string value) {
        StringValue = value;
    }

    public string StringValue {get; private set;}
}
```

Here's how I use it:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ISourceA, Dto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ISourceB, Dto>();

        var ms = new MultiSource(234, "woefjweofij");
        var ss = new StringSource("iuahergiuw");

        // This one is fine
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Mapper.Map<Dto>((ISourceA)ms)));
        // This one is the same as that above. This is not what I intended to have in return :/ 
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Mapper.Map<Dto>((ISourceB)ms)));
        // This works as expected
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Mapper.Map<Dto>(ss)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you copy the code from the fiddle here, to make it easier for people answering to see it?

Comment: which class does not recognize the interface/s ?

Comment: @dennisanberlin The `MultiSource`. If you use it as latter interface it does not work with automapper :/ You can see it by running the program. The second mapping is exactly the same as first one which is not what I intended

Comment: Not possible: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1295